# I need to add linear regression trend lines to qplot from ggplot2

Tags: r

Can someone suggest code modifications that will result in the overlay two trend lines, one for each group(designated by color)?

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0,10,.1)
y <- as.matrix(cbind(rnorm(101,x,1),rep(x,length(x)),rep(1,length(x))))
z <- as.matrix(cbind(rnorm(101,x+3,1),rep(x,length(x)),rep(0,length(x))))
data <- rbind(y,z)
qplot(y=data[,1],x=data[,2],col=data[,3])
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added some names to the df to make it easier and split everything out into separate layers in ggplot to make manipulation easier, imho.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0,10,.1)
y <- as.matrix(cbind(rnorm(101,x,1),rep(x,length(x)),rep(1,length(x))))
z <- as.matrix(cbind(rnorm(101,x+3,1),rep(x,length(x)),rep(0,length(x))))

# move the matrix to a df
data <- as.data.frame(rbind(y,z))

# give it some names to make life easier
names(data) <- c("Y","Z","X")

# note the benefit to qplot as well
qplot(y=data$Y,x=data$Z,col=data$X)

ggplot(data) + 
    aes(x=data$Z, y=data$Y, col=as.factor(data$X)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: The `as.factor` call isn’t necessary, and removing it ensures that we get proper labelling. same for `data$Z` and `data$Y`: just use `Z` and `Y` instead.

Comment: I tried it with no `as.factor` initially myself. It results in only a single regression line being generated. Try it. As for the data$NAME, I agree, is cleaner, but I wanted to make certain that it was obvious what was going on in ggplot since the OP had used X,Y,Z as their labels.

Comment: Ah, yes, because `X` is numeric, so ggplot (sanely) assumes a continuous value. For discrete values (factor, character …) it assumes discrete groups.

Answer (score 3):

With qplot:

```
 qplot(x = data[, 2], y = data[, 1], col = as.factor(data[, 3]),
     geom = c("point", "smooth"), method="lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

With ggplot:

```
data_df <- data.frame(y = data[, 1], x = data[, 2], grp = as.factor(data[, 3]))
ggplot(data_df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = grp)) + geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```